# (Python) Why do I have to redefine variable in while loop of Bisection Search?

Tags: python

I'm currently doing the edx MITx: 6.00.1x course and I'm have a problem with the Bisection Search lecture.

So I'm trying to use Bisection Search to find the cube root of a number, and would like to ask why Code 1 works and Code 2 does not.

**Code 1:**

```
x = 27
low = 1
high = 27
epsilon = 0.01
guess = (high + low) / 2

while abs(guess**3 - x) >= epsilon:
    if guess**3 > x:
        high = guess
    else:
        low = guess

print(guess)
```

**Code 2**

```
x = 27
low = 1
high = 27
epsilon = 0.01
guess = (high + low) / 2

while abs(guess**3 - x) >= epsilon:
    if guess**3 > x:
        high = guess
    else:
        low = guess
    guess = (high + low) / 2

print(guess)
```

Code 2 worked as I redefined the *guess variable* at the end of the while loop by adding guess = (high + low) / 2.

But in Code 1, the *guess variable* is already defined as guess = (high + low) / 2 outside of the loop. Shouldn't the value of the *guess variable* automatically change as long as either the *high variable* or *low variable* changes?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Numbers are immutable in Python (and they don't form "relationships" with the arguments used to calculate them)

Comment: @UnholySheep not related to immutability at all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok Let me use an analogy to try to explain this.

Let's say there is a cookie jar with 3 cookies in it and you are told that you can take as many as you want from that jar right now. You go an take all of them out. You now have 3 cookies.

If I now go and put 3 more cookies into the jar. Are you suddenly holding 6 cookies? or would you have to go get the cookies out.

That is the same concept with this variable.
You set the variable to a defined value and then later on changed those values.

Comment: it's not about immutability. The first part was okay though.

Comment: I removed that part from the answer and only left the relevant part.

Comment: nice. I really like this cookie jar thing so +1.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
guess = (high + low) / 2
```

binds the name "`guess`" to a value referring to an underlying object, which is the evaluated result of the expression to the right of `=`, namely `(high + low) / 2`, which is a number.  In Python, numbers are [immutable](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html). Unless yo bind the name `guess` again to another value, it keeps holding reference to the same underlying numeric object.

In Python, you don't define variables. You bind names.

Comment: it's not about immutability at all. With lists you would have the same behaviour. It's just that `(high + low) / 2` isn't computed automatically when the variables change.